# Azure Active Directory, many small requests vs few large requests

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way of interacting with Azure AD via Graph API when creating new users.

The problem is, i am importing a set of users from upload file. But before creating them in AD, i first get all the users from AD and the check if the username is already taken, if not i create the user.

What i am trying to understand, is it better to get all the users from AD at once or is it better to validate each user individually and make multiple calls to AD during the validation process?

Is there any resource i can refer to to get more insight on the issue?

Comment: I would say it depends on the number of users already exist vs. the number of users in your input file. If you need to check a large number of users, it would be beneficial to retrieve the entire user list from AAD and check it in memory. If it is a relatively small number of users that you need to check, it would probably be best to check them one at a time against AAD. In this case it seem to be all about the latency of requests to the Graph API endpoint.

Comment: The thing is the number of users keeps growing? Its currently reached a 1k. Also what i was thinking about, if Azure AD works like a database it would probably have more significant impact on AD to retrieve all users rather than getting a single user multiple times.

Comment: As fr as i understood from my client the upload files are not big less than 100 users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the amount of users you want to check is not large , you'd better check them with individual request rather than retrieving the entire user list from AAD .

You can use Microsoft Graph API [get user operation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/YourUPN
```

If user is not exist , it returns a 404 (not found). You can refer to [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) for getting access tokens to call Microsoft Graph . Code samples [here](https://github.com/search?q=aspnet%20sample%20user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories) are also for your reference .